# How to Open PDF/Docx in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-download-manager

I'm trying to allow the user to click on a pdf/doc link and be able to see it directly inside the webview. This is my code:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, 
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url);
    }
});
```

This correctly opens up a Google Viewer (I've also tried Google Viewer), but the contents that show up are the HTML source code, not the pdf/doc. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of Code:
final String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;

webView.loadUrl(url);

that's all

Comment: ..Is your problem Getting null pointer error in logcat? resolved or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Android WebView knows how to display PDF, docx, or other "non-native-Web" document formats. You'd have to pass the URL to another application to view it, or download it yourself and pass the local file to the other application.

Answer (score -1):

Use Google doc support to show doc or excel , pdf, txt or other formate.

```
WebView urlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
                + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {



    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```